# Is session a method or hash in Rails? Slightly confused

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session

Got a really simple question. I'm doing the railstutorial by Michael Hartl and it talks about using the session method:

Logging a user in is simple with the help of the session method defined by Rails... We can treat session as if it were a hash, and assign to it as follows:

```
session[:user_id] = user.id
```

It says you can treat session as if it were a hash, but I'm confused because it is called the session method, so is anything actually being called? My guess is that by inserting into the session hash, there is a session function that looks into the hash to see if there is anything present? I'm not really sure how it works.

Answer (score 4):

Would be rude not to mention the [`Session` documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#session):

> All session stores **use a cookie to store a unique ID for each session** (you must use a cookie, Rails will not allow you to pass the session ID in the URL as this is less secure).

Basically, each time someone visits your Rails app, it will create a small cookie in their browser, identifiable by a unique ID (**not** user ID).

This cookie is essentially a Ruby hash, hence why you can store hashed data inside it:

```
session[:your_hash] = "TEST"
```

This will allow you to store small snippets of data (such as `user_id` or others) through requests.

---

The main reason Rails has this is down to `HTTP` being a [*stateless* protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateless_protocol).

*Stateless* protocols are contrary to *stateful* protocols; they don't retain the state between requests, thus you have to reinvoke data, etc, each time a new instance of the application is accessed.

Simply, this translates into Rails being a "dumb" system - only remembering data you send it each request. [Session variables](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp) have been used by developers for decades to provide base information about users / preferences etc, allowing you to "rebuild" a user with each request.

This is why you have to save the `user_id` as a session - each time you wish to reference a logged-in user's data, it has to be built from that `id` stored in the sessions hash.

Answer (score 3):

It is a method that returns an object which supports (some of) the same methods a `Hash` object supports, such as `[]` and `[]=`. Actually, it is an `ActionDispatch::Request::Session` object.