# sessions in sinatra and creating a hash are similar?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I create a session, I have such code

```
# sinatra.rb
enable :sessions
get '/foo' do
  session[:message] = 'Hello World!'
  redirect to('/bar')
end

get '/bar' do
  session[:message]   # => 'Hello World!'
end
```

very similar to

```
# test.rb
session = Hash.new
session[:message] = 'Hello World!'
puts session
```

so what is the difference?

Comment: Here's how you can find out. Try the rest of Hash' API: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.4/Hash.html. If whatever is returned from `session` is not a hash, it won't conform to all of it (and that would be the difference).

Comment: Besides potentially different api, the main difference is that sinatra's feature persists data across requests, scoping to user's browser. Your hash does not.

Comment: found a similar topic but there Rails https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33293310/is-session-a-method-or-hash-in-rails-slightly-confused

Comment: All session stores use a cookie to store a unique ID for each session (you must use a cookie, Rails will not allow you to pass the session ID in the URL as this is less secure). This cookie is essentially a Ruby hash, hence why you can store hashed data inside it:

session[:your_hash] = "TEST"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure whether you are asking about the square brackets or you are interested in Sinatra's implmentation of `session`.

In case you are asking about the square brackets: they are nothing more than a method, which you can define in your own classes. Read more here: https://rickcarlino.com/2015/03/26/square_brackets-html.html

A small example extracted from the above url:

```
class FakeCollection
  attr_reader :items

  def initialize
    @items = {}
  end

  def [](index)
    @items[index] || "Not Found"
  end

  def []=(index, value)
    @items[index] = value
  end
end

example = FakeCollection.new

example[:x] = "Hello, world"

example[:x]
# => "Hello, world"
```